# Admin menu as submenu from another plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, admin-menu

I would like to add my new developed plugin's admin menu to an existing plugin as sub menu. Would be possible to do this?

In my first plugin I initilize the menus as follows:

```
function add_pages() {
    // Add a new top-level menu (ill-advised):
    add_menu_page(__('MyMenu','menu-test'), __('MyMenu','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'menu-top-level-handle', array ($this , 'menu_toplevel_page' ) );

    // Add a second submenu to the custom top-level menu:
    add_submenu_page('menu-top-level-handle', __('Test Submenu','menu-test'), __('Test Submenu','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'sub_page_test', array($this , 'test_sublevel_page2') );
}
```

The code in the second plugin:

```
function admin_menu () {    
    add_submenu_page( 'menu-top-level-handle', 'Lexikon', 'Lexikon', 'manage_options', 'lexikon-edit', array($this , 'lexikon_settings_page') );
}
```

Then I tried the following in my second plugin, but the page is wrong redirected instead: **`admin.php?page=sub_page`** redirects to **`/sub_page`**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to simulate the issue, it happened the same (`wp-admin/submenu_slug`), and the solution is to add a priority value in the hook `admin_menu`.

Here, I'm adding a sub menu to the plugin [BackWPup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/). Note the priority **`11`**:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'third_party_submenu_wpse_91377', 11 );

function third_party_submenu_wpse_91377() 
{
    add_submenu_page(
        'backwpup', // Third party plugin Slug 
        'My plugin', 
        'My plugin', 
        'delete_plugins', 
        'third_party_submenu', 
        'plugin_options_wpse_wpse_91377'
    );
}

function plugin_options_wpse_wpse_91377() 
{ 
    echo '<h1>OK</h1>'; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: More specifically, the priority of the action that adds the submenu item must be a higher number than the action that created the original menu. Otherwise your plugin will try to add a submenu to an item that hasn't been created yet.